# Potato ricer substitute

Tags: potatoes, grating

I'm looking to make potato gnocchi again but won't have a potato ricer. Is there another way to make the potato flour with it? Will a fine cheese grater work on a baked potato?

Answer (score 7):

You can scoop baked potato flesh out of the skins and press it through a sieve using the back of a spoon. This creates a similar effect to a ricer.
The potato flesh needs to be hot/warm to push through the sieve well.
You don't need to use too much pressure to get the potato through and be careful doing this as it does put rather a lot of strain on the sieve.

Answer (score 5):

Grater, food mill, masher, fork...the potato doesn't have to be all that fine.  Homemade potato gnocchi can be a bit rustic.  The key is not to overwork the potato, and then the dough once you add flour.

Answer (score 1):

I find that a coarse cheese grater works well. It's quick and easy, and doesn't crush the potato as much as other methods, so the gnocchi are fluffier.